# How to autoIncrement id value in sql using jdbcItemWriter

Tags: java, spring-batch

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Object> jobItemWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Object> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Object>();
    itemWriter.setDataSource(targetDataSource);
    itemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO customer (id,name,product) VALUES("Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS,:name,:product");
    return itemWriter;
}

@Bean
public Step slaveStep() {       
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
            .chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(jobItemReader(null, null))
            .chunk(fethcSize)
            .writer(jobItemWriter())
            .throttleLimit(gridSize)
            .build();
}
```

Hi I am trying to auto increment the value of primary key value using Spring Batch

Reading values from Source Customer table using JDBCItemReader jobItemReader()

Source Customer Table:
name
product

Target Customer Table
id -primary key
name
product

Output
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'customer.PRIMARY'

How can I increment the value of id in the jdbcItemWriter?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using plain `id` consider to use `nextval('hibernate_sequence')`

Comment: Hi Thanks! but I am using MySQL database

Comment: @AdiCoder, if id column is auto incremented, you do not need to give a value to it in your insert sql statement, just put name and product. mysql takes care of its value

Comment: Hi Ahmet, Yes that's correct but in case of parallel processing the jobs run sequentially if I do not give the value. I have 250K records for which I am using parallel processing.

Comment: @AdiCoder I updated my answer... maybe an acceptable soluce for you...

Answer (score 0):

Define in your customer table the `id`as `AUTO_INCREMENT`

like this

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ....
```

If you want to get value before insertion It won't be possible because the auto-increment is handle by the database at data insertion.

Maybe you can do this :

- insert a kind of empty-row data
- recover the autoincrement value that's been generated
- do your computations based on this id
- update the row to put the complete data roiw -- (by using the autoincrement generated earlier in the where clause of the update query, to identify which row is being updated)